# How to Execute Clojure File?

Tags: windows, clojure, clojure-contrib

How can I run a clojure file/script, which uses clojure-contrib, from the command line? My (winodws) machine has clojure-1.2.1.jar and clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar on the classpath. Note: I can start the REPL with: `java clojure.main`and I can execute *.clj files that DO NOT use clojure-contrib with: `java clojure.main file-name.clj`

Comment: If you are sure that clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar is on the classpath, I suggest verifying that the jar is a valid jar file, e.g. using this command: jar tvf clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar.  (Assumes the jar is in the current directory.)

Comment: if you could give us feedback about our answers, we might be able to help you further

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the clojure-contrib jar to the classpath. Since you are using windows, you add multiple classpaths by separating the entries with semicolons.

```
 java -cp clojure-1.2.1.jar;clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar clojure.main file-name.clj
```

The above code should enable you to run your file-name.clj script which depends on clojure-contrib.

Answer (score 2):

This line will run a clojure script "hello-world.clj". It first adds the clojure jar to the class path first and then will execute the file.

```
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main hello-world.clj
```

Comment: Downvoting.  The OP wanted to know how to run a clojure file/script that uses clojure-contrib.  Your example will not do that.

Comment: Upvoting because the reason for downvoting was silly. You've got to leave *something* as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: A careful re-reading of the OP's question will reveal that the OP is capable of running a script that depends only on clojure.core.  An answer stating, "Clojure depends on Java" would also leave something to the imagination but would also be deserving of a downvote because it, too, would do nothing to contribute to the OP's question.

Comment: @rayne I don't see it as self evident that "You've got to leave something as an exercise to the reader." Certainly answering the question shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

for those used to text editor + lots of shell work

lein run isn't bad
and lein projects can help you organize deps and other proj-specific